# CDT IASTFileLocation column number

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to get the location of each statement. Line position is ok, but got problem with column position. In jdt there is CompilationUnit that provide getColumnNumber()/getLineNumber(). But in cdt there is IASTTranslationUnit that doesn't provide similar functions.

```
 IASTTranslationUnit translationUnitparse(code.toCharArray());
        ASTVisitor visitor = new ASTVisitor() {
            @Override
            public int visit(IASTStatement statement) {

                    System.out.println(statement.getRawSignature());
                    IASTNodeLocation[] locations = statement.getNodeLocations();                   
                    if (locations.length == 1) {
                        IASTFileLocation astFileLocation = null;
                        if (locations[0] instanceof IASTFileLocation) {
                            astFileLocation = (IASTFileLocation) locations[0];
System.out.println(astFileLocation.getStartingLineNumber()+":"+astFileLocation.getEndingLineNumber());//Start/end line of statements
                             System.out.println(astFileLocation.getNodeOffset());
                             System.out.println( astFileLocation.getNodeOffset() + astFileLocation.getNodeLength());
                        }
                    }

                return ASTVisitor.PROCESS_CONTINUE;
            }
        };
```

There are also 2 functions getNodeOffset() and getNodeLength(). So how can I  get start/end column position of each statement in cdt?